# Как через Python управлять частотами звука Windows

Tags: python, pyaudio

Необходимо для системных звуков Windows 10 менять частотную характеристику. По сути сделать эквалайзер, которым можно например, увеличивать или уменьшать низкие или высокие частоты проигрываемого звука. Желательно с помощью PyAudio и без Qt

**Уточнение: ** имеются ввиду звуки, которые воспроизводятся с проигрывателя в Windows

Comment: Просто любопытно) Зачем для системных звуков эквалайзер?

Comment: @Александр имеются ввиду звуки, которые воспроизводятся с проигрывателя в Windows. Стандартный и сторонние эквалайзеры не интересуют. Нужно во время воспроизведения фильмов настраивать частоты

Comment: Покажите что у вас уже есть, и скажите что не получается.